# Equality of integrations

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification, convolution

I have a function $f(x)$ positive for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$. I also have functions $g,h,k$ and a constant $a$ s.t. for all $t$:

$$\int_0^t f(t-x) g(x)dx=- k(t)\int_0^t f(t-x) h(x)dx$$

So I propose that, if $k(t)\neq 0$, this is equal to

$$\int_0^t f(t-x) \left(\dfrac{g(x)}{k(t)}+h(x) \right) dx=0$$

Once $f(t-x)\geq 0$, so I must have $\dfrac{g(x)}{k(t)}+h(x)\equiv 0$ for all $x\leq t$. In particular, $g(t)=-h(t)k(t)$ for all $t$.

I did not see error on this calculation. However, it seems a little naive, so I 'd like to understand if this calculaton is correct. Thank you!

Comment: No, $z(t)\int\cdots\ne\int z(t)\cdots$.

Comment: @Christoph: sorry , I misread.

Comment: $\int_0^t f(t-x) K(t,x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$ for all $t$ and $f>0$ does not necessarily give $K(t,x)=0$ for all $x\in(0,t)$.  By the way, what is the constant $a$ doing in the question?

Comment: Why don't you consider $\int f(g+kh)\,dx$ and avoid a division ?

Comment: @user10354138 thank you! And you're right. The constant $a$ is not important (was in the original context).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Ok, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just consider the integral $\int_{-1}^1 x^2 \cdot x \,dx$. You have that $x^2 \ge 0$, the integral is zero, but $g(x)= x$ is not identically zero.

---

In this case, maybe you can get something out of differentiating both sides on the relation...

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_0^t f(t-x) g(x) dx = f(t-t)g(t) + \int_0^t f'(t-x)g(x) dx= \int_0^t f'(t-x)g(x) dx
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(-k(t) \int_0^t f(t-x) h(x) dx\right) = -k'(t) \int_0^t  f(t-x) h(x) dx -k(t) \int_0^t f'(t-x) h(x) dx 
$$

Comment: thank you so much. Do you know if can I to extract at least some information about $\left(\dfrac{g(x)}{k(t)}+h(x) \right)$ (or $g(x)+k(t)h(x)$)? I imagine that it must vary signal, so cross $0$ in some point... Anything else? Maybe you could also help me on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999267/quick-doubt-on-integral-negativity-leibniz-rule-on-a-direct-integral

Comment: Can you provide some context? Are some of those functions known? Can we may differentiate and get further relations?